# Invalid column index - Delete, using prepared statements

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, delete-row

This is code section:

```
public int deleteStatement() throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = getConnectivity(conn);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   

    String sql = "DELETE from USER_DETAILS where USERNAME=?";

    getConnectivity(conn);

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(4, "rother09");
    int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(rows + " DELETED");

    return rows;


}
```

```
Connection Valid
Connection Valid
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
atoracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.jav    a:5360)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5352)
atcom.platform.BilalsProject.DataAccessUtility.deleteStatement(DataAccessUtility.java:163)
at com.platform.BilalsProject.DataAccessUtility.main(DataAccessUtility.java:40
```

I am trying to delete from my table and it keeps giving me "invalid column index", can't see where I am going wrong.

In my database I have column 4 as password and 5 as username. The code works fine in sql worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

First thing why `getConnectivity(conn);` twice in the same method

Secondly your query 
`String sql = "DELETE from USER_DETAILS where USERNAME=?";` takes in one parameters
so in that case your `ps.setString(4, "rother09");`

should change to

```
ps.setString(1, "rother09");
```

Note it that `setString(int parameterIndex, String x)` doesnot mean you column index it actually means the index of the parameters used in the query suppose you query is like

```
SELECT * from USER_DETAILS WHERE USERNAME=? AND PASSWORD = ?
```

Then

```
ps.setString(1, "rother09");// for the first parameter i.e USERNAME
ps.setString(2, "password");// for the second parameter i.e PASSWORD
```